# how to get explanatory text on windows 10 screensaver

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

I have a Windows 10 laptop and desktop. The laptop has "bubbles" that you can click on to get more info about a background:

[image: Background with 'bubbles']

The desktop, however, does not:

[image: Background - plain]

I assume it's just a simple setting somewhere that'd enable these "bubbles" but idk what that setting is..

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of Windows Spotlight.

To enable go to:

> All Settings -> Personalization -> Lock Screen -> now choose "Windows
>   Spotlight" under the Background menu.

Unfortunately, if your desktop is an older build of Win 10 pro (prior to 10457), the feature may be unavailable.

Source: [Windows 10 Pro - No Windows Spotlight option in Lock Screen](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-10-pro-no-windows-spotlight-option-in-lock/b161b698-89d5-47b6-aaf1-498edb71184d)

[image]

Comment: The first screenshot (with the "bubbles") is from a Windows 10 Pro machine. A Microsoft Surface Pro 4 to be precise..

Comment: Yah just reading some more here. Apparently they have included it in newer pro builds, but it wasn't avail in older ones.

Comment: @CoscoTech - I went ahead and quoted the source link, the proper thing, to do when providing relevant links in an answer.  If your answer has changed you are responsible for updating it.